# Android make menu

Tags: android, menu, options-menu

I have made an options menu attached to my android menu button, but how do I make a list menu from clicking one of those menus (like the standard one you see when you go to android settings)

I must be doing the wrong google searches

Comment: Android Settings? That is not a menu, but a ListActivity or a ListView inside an Activity.

Comment: Nope, meant preferences! :)  Even after voted down I get the right answer from a more perceptive user, love this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [preferences](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)? ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html))

Comment: And you can launch preferences activity like any other activity, using intent.